# Update to 4.7.7 broke CiviCRM contact search

Tags: search, custom-search, quicksearch

I update to CiviCRM 4.7.7 from 4.7.6 and immediately got errors for my contact search.  The contact search in the upper left corner, Find contacts, and Advanced Search.  The error I get is:

@import url(http://www.mysite.org/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/css/civicrm.css); @import url(http://www.mysite.org/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css);    Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.

One of parameters (value: `1-street_address`) is not of the type MysqlColumnName

[Return to home page.](http://www.mysite.org/administrator/)

function toggle( element ) { var parent = element.parentNode; var className = parent.className; if ( className == 'crm-accordion-wrapper collapsed crm-fatal-error-details-block') { parent.className = 'crm-accordion-wrapper crm-fatal-error-details-block'; } else { parent.className = 'crm-accordion-wrapper collapsed crm-fatal-error-details-block'; } }

Anybody else having this problem?

Comment: One step to take would be to compare to what is happening at https://civicrm.org/sandboxes

Comment: hmm trying demo/demo and not getting in. sorry not being much help - tried at http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/ and hit no issues. Do you really have a column called 1-street_address - that sounds plain wrong. can you check your db

Comment: also confirm the CMS ;-)

Comment: Running CiviCRM 4.7.7 on Joomla 3.5.1, PHP 5.5.32, MySQL 5.5.49

Comment: The front end error shows: One of parameters (value: `Home-street_address`) is not of the type MysqlColumnName.  That is why this weird.  I dont have any custom code.  is there a way to check the db version info.  Maybe it didnt update??

Comment: Now that I go back to my test site, I get the same results.  I guess I didn't test it as thoroughly as I thought.  : (

Comment: From looking in the database the "1" is just the id for Home.  Basically same error then.

Comment: We're getting this problem too, after upgrading, except for us it's: One of parameters (value: `1-email`) is not of the type MysqlColumnName   --  you're not alone!

Answer (score 2):

This is a regression that has been identified in 4.7.7 - thanks for spotting it.

Progress on the issue, and a patch to resolve it, will be posted on the issue tracker here: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18510