# UPDATED State field selector and Profile Search not working

Tags: profile, search

Joomla 2.5.28
CiviCRM 4.7.7
PHP 5.5.30
MySQL 5.6.30

I have a Search Profile that allows a member to search for a local group based on Country and State OR they can search by name.

When the Country is selected, the state field does not populate.

You can see the page here:

https://www.theipca.org/index.php/local-guilds

**Updated 5/10: Search now works thanks to patch recommended by SleighD. When you do a successful search, the State field then works but still does not work on the initial Profile Search page.**

ISSUE BELOW THIS LINE HAS BEEN RESOLVED. STATE FIELD ISSUE PERSISTS.

*When you search for the local group by name, you get an error page.And you can search for Tallahassee in the Organization Name field.
Log file shows the following errors:

```
 May 09 14:21:52  [info] $backTrace = #0
> /home/ipca/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(371):
> CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
> #1 /home/ipca/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Type.php(424):
> CRM_Core_Error::fatal("One of parameters  (value:
> `Home-state_province`) is not of the type MysqlCol...")
> #2 /home/ipca/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Sort.php(124):
> CRM_Utils_Type::validate("`Home-state_province`", "MysqlColumnName")
> #3 /home/ipca/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Selector/Controller.php(222):
> CRM_Utils_Sort->__construct((Array:6), NULL)
> #4 /home/ipca/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Profile/Page/Listings.php(394):
> CRM_Core_Selector_Controller->__construct(Object(CRM_Profile_Selector_Listings),
> NULL, NULL, 4, Object(CRM_Profile_Page_Listings), 2)
> #5 /home/ipca/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Profile/Page/Router.php(124):
> CRM_Profile_Page_Listings->run()
> #6 /home/ipca/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(312):
> CRM_Profile_Page_Router->run((Array:2), NULL)
> #7 /home/ipca/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(86):
> CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
> #8 /home/ipca/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(54):
> CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:2))
> #9 /home/ipca/public_html/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(90): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:2))
> #10 /home/ipca/public_html/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(11): civicrm_invoke()
> #11 /home/ipca/public_html/libraries/joomla/application/component/helper.php(380):
> require_once("/home/ipca/public_html/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php")
> #12 /home/ipca/public_html/libraries/joomla/application/component/helper.php(348):
> JComponentHelper::executeComponent("/home/ipca/public_html/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php")
> #13 /home/ipca/public_html/includes/application.php(194): JComponentHelper::renderComponent("com_civicrm")
> #14 /home/ipca/public_html/index.php(42): JSite->dispatch()
> #15 {main}
```

Any ideas on how to fix?*

Comment: The patch resolved the search error problem, but not the issue with the State field being disabled. Will update ticket with same.

Comment: Hi Barbara - I see from your link that your state field is now working. I'm having this issue on another site of ours, can you let me know how you fixed it? Thanks

Comment: Sounds awful, but I don't remember. It was either a modsecurity rule change; updating ACL in civi for the profile or possibly looking at the visibility settings for the field in the profile. I should have documented the fix (I often do), but this was a week after my husband's eye surgery and all hell was breaking loose.

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer but I can't comment so....

Possible duplicate. See [Update to 4.7.7 broke CiviCRM contact search](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/11654/update-to-4-7-7-broke-civicrm-contact-search)

And https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18510

PATCH HERE: https://gist.github.com/mollux/d1fd488f56d13ded699c5620e603eb13

Tested, fixed my same issue.